# How to store user input in txt file?(Python 3)

Tags: python, file, text, storage

So i am writing a program and i made a function which stores user data in a txt file.It is like a simple registration function.The user gives the username and password to store.Problem is i can't store user input in the file.

My code is :

```
def reguser():      #Function name.

    fwu = open('user.txt','w')     #create or open user.txt file.
    user = input("Username: ")     #takes the user input.e.g what username to register
    fwu.write(user)                #this command should write input into the file
    fwp = open('pass.txt','w')     #create or open pass.txt file.
    pas  = input ("Password: ")    #takes user input e.g what password to register
    fwp.write(pas)                 #write the password into the file
    print ("To check for registraion completion, please login.")
    askuser()
```

So what i get is two text files user and pass but they are empty.
What am i doing wrong??
and please do not tell me to use modules for registraion.

Regards ali7112001

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't `fwu.close()` or `fwp.close()` (you didn't save it). Also a quick look up next time would save you some time. [.write not working in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972277/write-not-working-in-python)

Comment: @MooningRawr thanks man

Comment: No worries! Just trying to save you time, save people time, more time saved = more time coding and doing other things.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with `raw_input()` instead of input()

Also please `close()` the files.