# Output multiple f.write('x') commands for different URLS from python to txt file

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, spyder

I am trying to collect file one and file two and output both file one and file two to one text file. However, the return of my code into the text file is limited to the text of file one. How do I output `f.write(bio.text)` for both file one and file two? I imagine there must be a way for the computer to read these as independent requests, so that it simply performs one command after the other with file two listed below file one in the text file.

```
#File one
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://philosophy.nd.edu/people/faculty/anjan-chakravartty/'
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

bio = soup.find(class_='faculty-bio')

#file one output

f = open('philospohy.json', 'w')

f.write(bio.text)
f.close()


#File two

url = 'https://philosophy.nd.edu/people/faculty/patricia-blanchette/'
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

bio = soup.find(class_='faculty-bio')


#File two output
f = open('philospohy.json', 'w')
f.write(bio.text)
f.close()
```

Comment: Close your files when you're done with them. Or, better option, use the `with open() as f:` pattern.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.write not working in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972277/write-not-working-in-python)

Comment: I tried closing using f.close(), but that did not work. Additionally, I tried the with open() as f: method and it also did not work. Thanks for trying to help though. I really appreciate it!

Comment: That's weird, because I did it and it works fine. You should also read about your [file permissions with `open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open). `'w'` discards existing file contents.

Comment: I edited it to include the f.close(). This is not a duplicate, I checked the other page. Thanks again!

Comment: You're right, since you've edited it to not be a duplicate, it's now just a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change both lines with `f = open(‘philospohy.json’, ‘w’)` to `f = open(‘philospohy.json’, ‘a’, encoding = “utf8”)` and it should work. The reason is because when you open a file with the `w` mode it clears the whole thing and then writes to it. With the `a` mode, it just appends new text to the end. There was also the `encoding = “utf8”` that I added because all of the characters are not ASCII.