# There is no output from file.write

Tags: python, python-3.x

I run the following program and expect to get the output in a .txt file.

I have run this in spyder IDE with python 3.6.

```
temperatures = [10,-20,-289,100]

file = open('temperature.txt','w')

def f_to_c(temperatures):
    for celsius in temperatures:
        if  celsius >  -273.15:
            fahrenheit = celsius * (9/5) + 32
            file.write(str(fahrenheit))

f_to_c(temperatures)
```

There is **no error message** in this code, but I didn't get the output in the .txt file. Can you help?

Comment: You didn't close the file

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue (though I'm not using Spyder). You need to make a [mre].

Comment: In addition, your function should probably just return the values, and let the caller write to the file, or vice versa. The function should avoid referring to a global variable; that makes it harder to reuse, and breaks the encapsulation that you want a function to provide.

Comment: As @tripleee pointed out, `file` is not even explicitly a `global`, just happens to be in the outer scope - try to avoid such things. Improves readability and simplifies debugging. Also, consider using `with` syntax.

Comment: The specific reason nothing is written to your file is because you never close the file.  Add `file.close()` after your function call.

Comment: It's not off-topic for being unreproducible, nor is it a typo.  It is, however, a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972277/write-not-working-in-python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A cleaner approach below

```
def f_to_c(temperatures):
    fahrenheit_results = []
    for celsius in temperatures:
        if celsius > -273.15:
            fahrenheit_results.append(celsius * (9 / 5) + 32)
    return fahrenheit_results


results = f_to_c([10, -20, -289, 100])
with open('out.txt','w') as out:
    for r in results:
        out.write(str(r) + '\n')
```

Comment: It's even cleaner to make `f_to_c` a generator by replacing the `fahrenheit_results.append` call with a `yield` statement :)

Answer (score 1):

### Updated function and explanation:

```py
def f_to_c(file: str, temps: list):
    with open(file, 'a', newline='\n') as f:
        for temp in temps:
            if  temp >  -273.15:
                fahrenheit = temp * (9/5) + 32
                f.write(f'{fahrenheit}\n')


temps = [10,-20,-289,100]
f_to_c('temperature.txt', temps)
```

- Use `with open`, opens the file, only when the function is called.

  - **The specific reason you never get any output in your file, is because `file` is never closed.**
  - Using `with`, will automatically close the file.  [Reading and Writing Files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)
  - Opening the file inside the function, means you won't be looking to the outer scope, to find the `file` object.  [Scope of Variables in Python](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/scope-of-variables-python)
  - Use `a` to append to the file, each time the function is called.
- `f'{fahrenheit}\n'` is an [f-string](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/#f-strings-a-new-and-improved-way-to-format-strings-in-python).

  - [PEP 498 -- Literal String Interpolation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)
  - Using the f-string, there's no need to convert `fahrenheit`, using `str()`
- `(file: str, temps: list)` uses [PEP 484 - Type Hints](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/)

### Alternatively:

- Have a dedicated function for converting the temperatures.

  - This is the appropriate way do deal with the task.
  - Functions should do one thing.
- Deal with the file separately

```py
def f_to_c(temps: list) -> list:
    return [temp * (9/5) + 32 for temp in temps if temp > -273.15]


temps = [10,-20,-289,100]
with open('temperature.txt', 'a', newline='\n') as f:
    for value in f_to_c(temps):
        f.write(f'{value}\n')
```

- The function is implemented with [List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)
- [The `return` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=return#the-return-statement)