# write mouse position to .txt file

Tags: python, file

My little project is to write coordinates to file and my code look like this:

```
import pyautogui
import time

c = open("coord.txt", "w")
while True:
        x, y = pyautogui.position()
        positionStr = str(x).rjust(4) + str(y).rjust(4)
        print(positionStr)
        c.write(positionStr)
        time.sleep(1)
```

It not work becouse it show in terminal the coordinates but file coord.txt is still empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just missing to `flush` inside the loop. The `write` method doesn't necessarily write the data to disk. You have to call the `flush` method to ensure this happens.

```
import pyautogui
import time

c = open("coord.txt", "w")
while True:
    x, y = pyautogui.position()
    positionStr = str(x).rjust(4) + str(y).rjust(4)
    print(positionStr)
    c.write(positionStr + '\n')
    c.flush()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Is better to replace `c = open("coord.txt", "a")` with `with open("coord.txt", "w") as c:` so when the loop end the file automatically close otherwise you need to call `close`.

```
import pyautogui
import time

with open("coord.txt", "w") as c:
    while True:
        x, y = pyautogui.position()
        positionStr = str(x).rjust(4) + str(y).rjust(4)
        print(positionStr)
        c.write(positionStr + '\n')
        c.flush()
        time.sleep(1)
```

You can also use the `print()` function to write to the file:

```
import pyautogui
import time

with open("coord.txt", "w") as c:
    while True:
        x, y = pyautogui.position()
        positionStr = str(x).rjust(4) + str(y).rjust(4)
        
        print(positionStr)
        print(positionStr, file=c, flush=True)

        time.sleep(1)
```

This is because the `print()` is defined as `print(object(s), sep=separator, end=end, file=file, flush=flush)` where:

- `object(s)`: Any object, and as many as you like. Will be converted to string before printed
- `sep='separator'`: Optional. Specify how to separate the objects, if there is more than one. Default is `' '`
- `end='end'`: Optional. Specify what to print at the end. Default is `'\n'` (line feed)
- `file`: Optional. An object with a write method. Default is `sys.stdout`
- `flush`: Optional. A Boolean, specifying if the output is flushed (`True`) or buffered (`False`). Default is `False`

Answer (score 1):

Remember to do `c.close()` or `c.flush()` after you write the file.

Maybe duplicate of [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972277/write-not-working-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

you need to change mode from `w` to `a` so that it can append to a file.

```
import pyautogui
import time

with open("coord.txt", "a") as writer: #This is better so that you dont have to worry about closing the file
    while True:
        x, y = pyautogui.position()
        positionStr = str(x).rjust(4) + str(y).rjust(4)
        print(positionStr)
        writer.write(positionStr+"\n")
        time.sleep(1)
```