# Write coordinates to .txt file to future use it in program

Tags: python, file

I create code that after click show me coordinates where it was clicked, and my problem is appending this thing to txt file named coord.txt the code is:

```
from pynput import mouse

def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    c=open("coord.txt", "w+")
    if button == mouse.Button.left:
        print(x, y)
        c.write(x)
        c.write(y)
        return False
    c.flush()
listener = mouse.Listener(on_click=on_click)
listener.start()
listener.join()
```

and the error is:

```
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not int
```

but nothing help that i try. In the future i want to pair this def with all my toolbuttons in pyqt5 gui that look like this:
https://github.com/spokom/mycodes/tree/master

Comment: What *did* you try? It should be as simple as converting `x` and `y` to strings before passing them to `c.write`.

Comment: Did you not already solve this in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64046117/write-mouse-position-to-txt-file)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert `x` and `y` to strings in order to write them.

Also, you should separate them with a delimiter, otherwise when you try to read them back you'll just get a single number.

```
def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    with open("coord.txt", "w") as c:
        if button == mouse.Button.left:
            print(x, y)
            c.write(str(x) + "\n")
            c.write(str(y) + "\n")
            return False
```

There's no need to use the `+` modifier in your open mode. You're only writing the file, not reading from it as well.

Answer (score 0):

The error message says to convert `int` value in `string`. Replace your `write(x)` with `write(str(x))`. Do the same for the other write operation.

Answer (score 0):

As the error describes, your x and y are ints. Verify this by using:

`print(type(x), type(y))`

Convert both variables to string before passing them in.

`str(x), str(y)`

[Quick learning point.](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-integer-to-string-in-python/)