# Why are my bytes not being written to my file?

Tags: python

I'm making a system, where you take a string, encrypt it, and write to a file. Here is how I do it:

```py
data = "My secret data!"
datastoreName = "Datastore"
datastore = open(datastoreName + ".txt", "wb")
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
key = Fernet.generate_key()
fernet = Fernet(key)
encData = fernet.encrypt(data.encode())
datastore.write(encData)
```

Whenever I run it, nothing gets to written the datastore.txt, and there is no errors shown. What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

Comment: First thing that sticks out is that you don't close the file.

Comment: You need to close or flush the file. Better yet, use [`with` to do this for you](https://peps.python.org/pep-0343/). That is the pythonic way to access files anyway

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972277/write-not-working-in-python Unfortunately I jumped the gun on my close vote

Comment: How are you determining that nothing is written?

Comment: Your code works for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.write not working in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972277/write-not-working-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue you are having is related to you not closing the file. When you write/read a file in python, you should use a context manager. Basically, it closes the file once you are done using it. What you did was open the file, then left the file open and the script ended so Python never actually saved anything to the file. In fact, it can sometimes be dangerous to not close files since in more complicated programs it can cause corruption. What you should probably do using a context manager is:

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

data = "My secret data!"
datastoreName = "Datastore"
key = Fernet.generate_key()
fernet = Fernet(key)
encData = fernet.encrypt(data.encode())

with open(datastoreName + ".txt", "wb") as datastore:
  datastore.write(encData)
```

The `with` statement automatically closes the file after you are done editing it. Note that anything not indented under the `with` statement will not edit the file.