# How does os.path.getsize() work within a "with" block in Python?

Tags: python, file-io, operating-system

The `fun(filename)` function creates a new file passed to it as a parameter, adds some text and then returns its size. When `print(os.path.getsize(filename)` is used within the 'with' block it doesn't work as intended.

```
import os

def fun(filename):
    with open(filename,'w') as file:
        file.write("hello")
        print(os.path.getsize(filename))

fun("newFile2.txt")
```

It outputs `0`. But when `print(os.path.getsize(filename)` is used outside the 'with' block as

```
import os

def fun(filename):
    with open(filename,'w') as file:
        file.write("hello")
    print(os.path.getsize(filename))

fun("newFile2.txt")
```

Then it prints the correct output: `5`. What's going on behind the scenes?

Comment: The file will written completely when it is flushed or closed, like at the end of the `with` block.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972277/write-not-working-in-python

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the buffered nature of writing to files. When you close the file, i.e., exit the `with` block, the rest of the buffered input gets written to the file. You can read more about python buffering modes used in open here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open